# Creating a loop inside GtkDialog

Tags: c++, gtk

I have a GtkDialog set up like this:

```
GtkWidget *dialog;
dialog = gtk_message_dialog_new(GTK_WINDOW(window),
        GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT,
        GTK_MESSAGE_INFO,
        GTK_BUTTONS_OK,
        "Information");
gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(dialog), "Information");
gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(dialog));
gtk_widget_destroy(dialog);
```

However, when the dialog is open I want to have an infinite loop, which would be exited when the OK button is pressed. Is something like that possible to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run `gtk_dialog_run` in a do/while loop and test its return value in the `while`. That return value tells you which button has been pressed (most probably `GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT` in your case).

Please read the documentation for `gtk_dialog_run`, that's explained there.

Comment: Please also note this is bad practice to not allow the user to change his mind, and displaying a cancel button just to taunt him is even worse. The right solution is to avoid that infinite loop by allowing the user to cancel.